# showing restricted metric still forms a complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(A,d)$ be complete. Let $B$ be a closed subset of $A$. Then show the metric space $(B,d|_{B\times B})$ is complete.

I have shown from a theorem that $(B,d)$ is complete, but I am not sure how to use this ot show that $(B,d|_{B \times B})$ is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sentence involving "$(X,d)$ is a metric space" requires $d$ to defined on $X\times X$. So $(B,d|_{B \times B})$ has indeed a meaning, but $(B,d)$ means nothing as your $d$ is not defined on $B\times B$ in general, except that almost everyone would do the abuse of notation/language consisting in identifying $d$ and its restriction to $B\times B$, $d|_{B \times B}$. So when you say you have shown that $(B,d)$ is complete (surely showing that $B$ is closed in $A$), you have in fact shown what you want, that is, that $(B,d|_{B \times B})$ is complete.

Comment: I have proved that for a complete metric space $(A,d)$ and $B\subset A$ is closed then $(B,d)$ is complete iff $B$ is closed in $A$. But I am then later asked the same question I posted - surely they must have different solutions

Comment: Do you understand what I wrote in my answer ?

Comment: yes, well I think so. You are trying to say that the above theorem I posted in my comment actually means for $d$ restricted to $B \times B$ - I'm trying to figure out why my lecturer would prove this theorem for us then later give us a question which asks the exact same thing (if what you're saying is correct)

Comment: If this is exactly what your lecturer asked for, then your lecturer made a mistake. If he defined what "B is complete for d defined on AxA" means, and then asked to you to prove that it is equivalent to "B is complete for d|BxB", then it is not a mistake, but a bad lecturer.

Comment: The exact wording of the quesiton is: Let $(A,d)$ be a complete metric space and $B \subset A$ be a closed set. Denote by $d|_{B \times B}$ the restriction of $d$ to $B \times B$. Prove that the metric space $(B, d|_{B\times B})$ is complete. The exact wording of the theorem is: if $(A,d)$ is a complete metric space and $B \in A$, then $(B,d)$ is complete if and only if $B$ is closed in $A$. And you are saying these are equivalent questions? (well one going one way, the other doing both implications).

Comment: Ok, the theorem is bad stated, it should be "then $(B,d|_{B\times B}$ is complete if and...", not $(d,b)$. But it is bad stated because of the obvious abuse of notation I described in my answer, which is not a problem, as almost everyone would get that (B,d) means $B$ equipped with the restriction of d to BxB. Eveything's clear ?

Comment: Yes it's clear, but I'm just wondering why he would ask that question if they are identical as you say (and indeed proved the theorem)

Comment: Maybe he just wants you to prove the theorem again as an exercise. There are basically only two possible proofs : showing that every Cauchy sequence of elements of B converges in B using that A is complete and B is closed, or be quicker and show that as A is complete, every consequence of elements of B converges in A, and in fact in B, as B is closed. I don't know which proof he gave (if he gave one) but maybe he wan't you to give the other proof.

Comment: Np ! You're welcome !